# Prove that $n^2 \leq \frac{c^n+c^{-n}-2}{c+c^{-1}-2}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction

Let $c \not= 1$ be a real positive number, and let $n$ be a positive integer.

Prove that $$n^2 \leq \frac{c^n+c^{-n}-2}{c+c^{-1}-2}.$$

My initial thought was to try and induct on $n$, but the negative powers annoyed be badly.

I still think that induction is the way to go, but maybe it is something more clever than I am doing. Although perhaps induction is unhelpful, and I simply need to use inequalities to do this, like AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz. But even there I get very stuck. I have a feeling that there is some neat thing I should do to make this a lot simpler.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $c^n + c^{-n}-2 = \left(\sqrt{c}^{\,n} - \sqrt{c}^{\,-n}\right)^2$, and something similar is true of the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the RHS is $$\frac{-(1-c^n)(1-c^{-n})}{-(1-c)(1-c^{-1})}$$

To clarify my bonus hint, we may rearrange the AM-HM inequality to state $$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)(\frac 1a_1+\frac 1a_2+\cdots+\frac 1a_n)\ge n^2$$

Comment: Bonus hint: AM >= HM

Comment: Don't you think that GM is more helpful???

Comment: As we can say that $n^2 \leq \frac {c^n+c^{-n}-2}{c+c^{-1}-2}=\frac{-(1-c^n)(1-c^{-n})}{-(1-c)(1-c^{-1})}=\frac{(1-c^n)(1-c^{-n})}{(1-c)(1-c^{-1})}=(1+c+c^2+c^3+ \cdots c^{n-1})(1+c^{-1}+c^{-2}+c^{-3}+c^{-4}+c^{-5}+ \cdots c^{-(n-1)}) \geq  n(c^{\frac{(n-1)(n)(-n)}2}) \cdot n(c^{-\frac{(n-1)(n)(-n)}2})$ By AM-GM which is equal to $n^2 \frac{c^{\frac{(n-1)(n)(-n)}2}}{c^{\frac{(n-1)(n)(-n)}2}}=n^2$

Comment: @JohnMarty, that works too...

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for the neat factorization.

Comment: My pleasure.  The AM-HM trick comes up a lot...